# Python Cassandra Connection Pooling

Tags: python, cassandra, rabbitmq

I am looking to using Cassandra's session shared by multiple pythons threads.
What my flow is I have a rabbitmq consumer. For each message received consumer inserts data to Cassandra.
There are 3 consumers each consumer is provided a Cassandra cluster object. When a consumer receives a message it uses this cluster object and inserts it into cassandra. But when a message has received the `session.execute(query)`gets stuck.

```
ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=self.connection_params['username'],
                                       password=self.connection_params['password'])
            cluster = Cluster(contact_points=self.connection_params['contact_points'],
                                   port=self.connection_params['port'], idle_heartbeat_interval=10,
                                   auth_provider=ap, connect_timeout=30, protocol_version=3,
                                   load_balancing_policy=DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(), monitor_reporting_enabled=True)
session = self.cluster.connect()
            session.set_keyspace(self.connection_params['keyspace'])
            session.row_factory = dict_factory
            session.encoder.mapping[list] = session.encoder.cql_encode_tuple
```

Rabbitmq onMessage I am passing this session object.

Comment: look to documentation - it explains how to use Python driver from multiple threads

Comment: @AlexOtt i tried it but it doesnt work.